# Does Dungeon Raid ever end?

Tags: ios, dungeon-raid

I recently picked up a copy of [*Dungeon Raid*](http://dungeonraid.atspace.com/) on my iPhone.  To my surprise, it has quickly become my favorite iPhone game.  Having never played an RPG-style game since the NES's *Dragon Warrior*, I'm learning some new skills.

**Does anyone know if the game actually has an end?**  Or do you just keep playing forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you just keep playing forever at increasingly harder difficulty.

Comment: Ah, well.  I was hoping there was an ending for each one of its silly intro stories.  I typically don't like endless games, but this one has me hooked.  At least for now.